# Microsoft Graph People API - Topic Search

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-people

Can you let me know how a Topic search works in People API? 
Is this query correct:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people/?$search="topic: microsoft"

I'm not getting relevant results.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Can you be more specific what do you mean by "not getting relevant results"? Are you getting some error, no results, or something else you think is wrong about those results?

Comment: Hi Prokurors, thanks for reaching out. When I search for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people/?$search="topic:design" -  we got the following response:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('2e818564-4858-4ff5-a0be-98c56ef5d792')/people",
    "value": []
}